# Beach Umbrellas puzzle: did I make a mistake or is Brainzilla wrong?

Tags: logical-deduction, logic-grid, explanation, solvability

https://www.brainzilla.com/logic/logic-grid/beach-umbrellas/ has the following puzzle:

> Four families are going to the beach in the morning and are bringing
> their family-size umbrellas. Which family has the yellow umbrella?
>
> 1. The green umbrella shields 5 people.
> 2. Family Thorpe arrived at the beach one hour after the family with the blue umbrella, and one hour earlier than the largest family.
> 3. Family Kendal has the green or yellow umbrella. They have one more family member than Bensons.
> 4. Ridleys don't have the white umbrella and aren't the smallest family.
> 5. The smallest family doesn't have the yellow umbrella.
> 6. If the Kendals arrived at 8:00, then the largest family arrived at 9:00.
> 7. If the family with the green umbrella arrived at 7:00, then Ridleys are 6 people.

According to that website, this is the correct solution:

| Family | Time | Umbrella | Members |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Benson | 8:00 | blue | 4 |
| Kendal | 7:00 | green | 5 |
| Ridley | 10:00 | yellow | 6 |
| Thorpe | 9:00 | white | 3 |

But consider these other two solutions:

| Family | Time | Umbrella | Members |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Benson | 7:00 | blue | 4 |
| Kendal | 10:00 | green | 5 |
| Ridley | 9:00 | yellow | 6 |
| Thorpe | 8:00 | white | 3 |

| Family | Time | Umbrella | Members |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Benson | 10:00 | green | 5 |
| Kendal | 9:00 | yellow | 6 |
| Ridley | 7:00 | blue | 4 |
| Thorpe | 8:00 | white | 3 |

It seems to me that all three of those are valid, but the website says that only the first is correct, and that the second two are both wrong. Am I missing something, or is the website wrong?

Comment: Yea, probably the website wanted "if and only if" instead of "if" for clue 6 (invalidates solution 3) and 7 (invalidates solution 2), which only allows first solution.

Answer (score 1):

There would need to be better wording if I am true, but my best guess would be

> Rules 6 and 7 mean if **and** only if, not just if.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any reason for the second solution to be invalid, but the third could be considered invalid because:

> One can infer from clue 6 that the Kendals are not the largest family, even if the Kendals don't arrive at 8:00.

Comment: Aren't statements supposed to be equivalent to their contrapositives? And you can't infer that from its contrapositive, can you?

Comment: The contrapositive is "If the largest family did not arrive at 9:00, then the Kendals did not arrive at 8:00". That still heavily implies that the Kendals and the largest family are two distinct entities. That implication is independent of the if-then logical structure of the sentence, but merely from the fact that both terms are used in the same sentence. It would be weird violation of the [cooperative principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cooperative_principle) for both terms to refer to the same entity.

Comment: I would definitely make this assumption if there statement were from everyday discourse… but in the context of a logic puzzle I’d only go by the literal meaning, which does not state that the Kendals are not the largest family.